# Oracle: How to check whether the given array exists in the table?

Tags: oracle

I want to check whether the array of values (4690, 4693) both is exists in the contextid column without using functions as the table contains more that a million records
Table structure:

| ID | CONTEXTID |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 4690 |
| 5 | 4690 |
| 6 | 4693 |
| 7 | 4693 |
| 8 | 4690 |

Comment: How do you plan to input an array of values to the query? HINT: the very common attempt to give a string, which is a comma-separated list of values, is a poor option. In any case, let us know what you are doing with that.

Answer (score 0):

What about this query?

```
select 
  case when count(distinct CONTEXTID) = 2 then 'Y' else 'N' end as contains_4690_4693
from tab
where CONTEXTID in (4690, 4693)
```

it retuns `Y` if both keys are in the table *at least once*, `N` otherwise.

Comment: Whether is there anyway to do without using functions as the table contains more that a million records

Comment: Do you have a index of the column `CONTEXTID`? @Raghul if yes it will be used, if not simple open a cursor reading the table and fetch until you find both keys - if you want to "optimize"; but I'm not sure if it will be on average *better* that the `count` using *full table scan*.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find out if they exist then

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONTEXTID)
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  wHERE CONTEXTID IN (4690, 4693)
```

will do it. If CONTEXTID isn't indexed, though, the database will have to do a full table scan which will probably be slow.

Takeaway: add an index on CONTEXTID or live with the fact that it's going to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

If the "test" values are known when you write the query (as they very rarely are - even though all the solutions presented so far make the implicit assumption that they are), you could do something like this - which is probably the most efficient way, regardless of whether there is an index on the relevant column or not:

```
select case when exists 
       ( select * 
         from   sys.odcinumberlist(4690, 4693)
         where  column_value not in ( select contextid 
                                      from   the_table 
                                      where  context_id is not null
                                    )
       ) then 'Not all found' else 'All found' end as result
from   dual
;
```

Note how I gave an array of input values to the query - I used the `sys.odcinumberlist` constructor. You will have to clarify how you plan to "input" an array of "test" values.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach, but it would be valuable to add, why it is *the most efficient way* compared with the first answer, resp. with its *one hour later clone* by @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica . My impression: without index your approach will be somehow better *if the table contains the keys*, but equal to the `count distinct` if the keys are missing. (The difference will go down with the increased number of keys). With an *index* your approach will open an `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` that will be probably outperformed by a single two key index access of the `count distinct` solution